# New job, coworker took tips for himeself. Should I tell manager?

Tags: salary, colleagues

I recently started working in a retail store. We have a tip jar. Someone tipped a large bill. When we were closing I asked my coworker where the tips were and he lied saying there were none.

In fairness 1) I wasn't the one working at the POS at the time the tip was made 2) I haven't been informed of any official policy regarding how tips are divided. That being said it's common to divide the tips evenly. 3)  we don't have change in the till because we're not accepting cash at the moment because of covid. This is management's decision, it's not government ordered. So it would have been hard to split but I did have change in my wallet.

What should I do? Should I ask the manager what the policy is? There's two people working each shift, should I just make an agreement with the other? I don't want this to turn into a battle of who gets to work POS and keep the tips and who gets stuck working the other tasks. Come to think of it, the same person probably did this another time.

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Get your part of that tip, get that coworker reported, have whatever policy is in place changed,...?

Comment: Get my portion of the tip. Get clarity on the policy. Bring attention to my coworkers dishonest conduct.

Comment: These are 3 different goals... I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: If you’re not accepting cash because your management thinks it’s not safe, why is there a tip jar out for people to put cash in?

Comment: @ColleenV - indirect emotional pressure on customers to leave a bigger tip.

Comment: Did you see the 20 (10? 100?) placed in the jar by a customer? Is it possible the employee placed it there as a seed?

Comment: @Donald I know why tip jars are put out. My question is how accepting cash tips is consistent with not accepting cash payments, i.e. if the management is not OK with cash changing hands because of COVID, they should probably not be OK with the tip jar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there was some kind of policy implying that whoever runs the POS keeps the change, your colleague would probably have told you instead of lying about no getting any tip...

What I would do is indeed ask about policy, and if it is indeed to split, I wouldn't report the coworker for this time (unless we're really talking about a meaningful amount of money... we sometimes hear of very generous tips...) but let him know it didn't go unnoticed and you would appreciate it doesn't happen anymore in the future, or you would have to report it.

Why not reporting right away? Cause you indicate you started recently, and you might not want to start a fight with this colleague over a presumably small amount of money, even if you would be in your right.

UPDATE after further clarification from OP, mentioning 3 goals:

**Get clarity on the policy**

This is the first step in any case. Before anything, you need to know whether this coworker indeed broke policy or not. That's also the easiest goal to achieve, just ask a manager.

**Get your portion of the tip**

Assuming the policy is to split. I see 2 possible ways of doing that: reporting this colleague (see below), or approach him around the lines of

> look, I know the policy is to split and I know this customer left $20. I don't want to report you over $10 but I would appreciate if this doesn't happen anymore in the future. Additionally I would also appreciate to get these $10."

Don't be threatening, people don't react well to threats. And keep to your words, don't report him if you say so.

**Bring attention to your coworker's dishonest conduct**

If the goal is to bring attention to this guy's behavior, then there is no other way than report him, once again assuming this was a misconduct regarding tips policy. If you go up to there, don't mention anything like "probably did this before" but focus on this specific occurrence you are sure of. It would obviously help to have some kind of proof (CCTV footage). By doing this you can also probably achieve your previous goal to get your share of the tip. But don't expect this coworker to be too friendly afterwards...

Comment: I mean the tip was $20 which is pretty big as far as tips go. I guess I can let it slide this time.

Comment: @user104163 20$ isn’t insignificant...but you don’t want to ruin your work life there over 10$ it’s literally not worth it. Go without it once, but do follow up on policy. Unfortunately there are dishonest people, you may also find out your manager knows too, and doesn’t care...

Comment: Good point. I spoke with management and the coworker is quitting anyway.

Answer (score -2):

> We have a tip jar. Someone tipped a large bill. When we were closing I asked my coworker where the tips were and he lied saying there were none.

If you saw someone put $20 bucks into the tip jar and later on the co-worker said the jar had no tip, then I would be suspicious of this. For starter, assuming the policy was in his favor, he would have simply said, "Yes, I took the tip since it was mine." Instead, he decided to lie and say there was none so you wouldn't have anything to say.

With that said, I would do like others said here and ask about the policy on how the tip will be split. Not only that, I would ask how do they know how much tip was in the jar?

Afterwhich, I would monitor it more closely. If you were entitled to the tips, per policy, then you should and ought to get the tip after closing.